# A grafia brasileira é aceita em exames portugueses e vice-versa?

Tags: ortografia

Sou brasileiro e atualmente estou a cursar o 11º ano do ensino secundário (equivale ao 2º ano do ensino médio no Brasil). Eu comecei a estudar em Portugal no ano letivo anterior (2017-2018) e ainda não estou devidamente acostumado à grafia portuguesa das palavras.

Esse é um assunto que me preocupa, uma vez que vou realizar os exames nacionais do 11º brevemente e não tenho a certeza se a grafia brasileira é aceita nos exames nacionais do ensino secundário.

Na minha cabeça, é lógico que seja aceita por se tratar da mesma língua e pelos acordos ortográficos que dão dor de cabeça para ambos os lados, mas nunca tive uma resposta concreta que me deixasse descansado.

**TL;DR**
A grafia brasileira é aceita em exames nacionais portugueses?

Comment: Caio, já perguntaste aos teus professores? Alguns deles provavelmente corrigem exames. Eu também penso que seja aceite (não sei mesmo se erros ortográficos são significativamente penalizados, quanto mais... no meu tempo não eram, ou eu não teria entrado na universidade). Se não pudesses obter melhor conselho que o meu, eu diria para escreveres na norma brasileira e colocares uma nota no início a dizer isso mesmo. (A minha correção ortográfica da tua pergunta respeita a norma brasileira; e a portuguesa também ;)  -- a eliminação do agradecimento é norma do site.)

Comment: Caio, a tua pergunta é apenas sobre a aceitação da Grafia Brasileira em Portugal? Ou tbm o oposto? Grafia Portuguesa no Brasil (pois colocou vice-versa na tua pergunta) Eu tenho muita convicção que a grafia portuguesa não é aceita no Brasil. Por exemplo, não poderíamos escrever *contacto* em uma redação de vestibular no Brasil.

Comment: @Jacinto, é uma boa ideia, vou entrar em contato com a minha professora.

Comment: @Peixoto sim, também a respeito da grafia portuguesa no Brasil. Acho justo que seja válido nos dois sentidos, vou procurar saber mais a respeito.

Comment: Quando eu fiz vestibular, isso há mais de 20 anos, a orientação já era escrever com a ortografia brasileira.

Comment: Mas @Peixoto, claro que a orientação em Portugal é escrever com a ortografia pt-PT... o que o Jacinto diz é que (com exceção óbvia para o exame de Português) não espera que o Caio seja penalizado nos exames por "escrever em brasileiro", da mesma forma que ele não foi penalizado por dar gralhas e erros gramaticais. Eu sou da mesma *opinião*.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer, é que no meu entender, o Brasil segue "a risca" os acordos ortográficos e é levado em conta na redação do vestibular, por exemplo. Esse critério, pelo o que vejo, não é o mesmo em Portugal

Comment: Boa questão... nem sei se nas escolas o acordo é seguido. Imagino que sim.

Comment: Acho interessante observar que dezenas de universidades portuguesas aceitam o resultado do Exame Nacional do Ensino Médio (ENEM) brasileiro como critério para a entrada, ou seja, claramente dispensando o conhecimento da variedade europeia. Já na pós-graduação, há brasileiros que acham mais fácil (seria também meu caso) escrever a tese ou dissertação em inglês do que tentar dominar o dialeto local (o que faz supor que a variedade brasileira não seria aceita).

Comment: Tipicamente no Brasil não se aceita grafia portuguesa. Pessoalmente, eu considero isso um absurdo. Também acho absurdo regularem a gramática. A língua é viva, impôr regras é um esforço inútil.

Answer (score -2):

Há algum tempo, houve um acordo ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa proposta por Portugal que atinge todos os falantes do português, o que inclui o país de Cabo Verde. O Brasil ADOTOU essas regras. A única diferença entre o português brasileiro e o lusitano são os significados das palavras, como "Bicha"(fila-PT), "PORRA"(alimento-PT), "RAPARIGA"(moça-PT), entre outras.

Comment: Wellington, obrigado pela resposta. Independe de qualquer coisa, sinto em dizer que estás bem errado. Sim, estamos, Brasil e Portugal, sob o Acordo Ortográfico, mas ainda é comum o uso do acordo prévio em ambos os países, sobretudo Portugal, contudo: escreve-se e fala *bilhão* no Brasil e *bilião*, com *trilhão*, *quadrilhão*, etc., idem; usam-se, em Portugal, *facto*, *excecional*, *aspeto* e *secção*, e *fato*, *excepcional*, *aspecto* e *seção* no Brasil.  Por mais de as variações estarem corretas em todos os países lusófonos, **nem todas elas são recomendadas**, >>

Comment: >> ou seja, um professor português pode chamar *aspecto* de errado, ou um brasileiro *aspeto* de errado, este é bem provável.